# Convert string date to a different format in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been looking for this answer in the community so far, could not have.

I have a dataframe in python 3.5.1 that contains a column with dates in string imported from a CSV file.

The dataframe looks like this

```
                  TimeStamp  TBD  TBD     Value  TBD
0       2016/06/08 17:19:53  NaN  NaN  0.062942  NaN
1       2016/06/08 17:19:54  NaN  NaN  0.062942  NaN
2       2016/06/08 17:19:54  NaN  NaN  0.062942  NaN
```

what I need is to change the TimeStamp column format to be
%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%D

```
                  TimeStamp  TBD  TBD     Value  TBD
0       06/08/2016 17:19:53  NaN  NaN  0.062942  NaN
```

So far I have found some solutions that works but for string and not for series

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you convert the column of strings to a time series, you could use the [`dt.strftime` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
nan = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'TBD': [nan, nan, nan], 'TBD.1': [nan, nan, nan], 'TBD.2': [nan, nan, nan], 'TimeStamp': ['2016/06/08 17:19:53', '2016/06/08 17:19:54', '2016/06/08 17:19:54'], 'Value': [0.062941999999999998, 0.062941999999999998, 0.062941999999999998]})
df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
print(df)
```

yields

```
   TBD  TBD.1  TBD.2            TimeStamp     Value
0  NaN    NaN    NaN  06/08/2016 17:19:53  0.062942
1  NaN    NaN    NaN  06/08/2016 17:19:54  0.062942
2  NaN    NaN    NaN  06/08/2016 17:19:54  0.062942
```

---

Since you want to convert a column of strings to another (different) column of strings, you could also use the vectorized `str.replace` method:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
nan = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'TBD': [nan, nan, nan], 'TBD.1': [nan, nan, nan], 'TBD.2': [nan, nan, nan], 'TimeStamp': ['2016/06/08 17:19:53', '2016/06/08 17:19:54', '2016/06/08 17:19:54'], 'Value': [0.062941999999999998, 0.062941999999999998, 0.062941999999999998]})
df['TimeStamp'] = df['TimeStamp'].str.replace(r'(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)(.*)', r'\2/\3/\1\4')
print(df)
```

since

```
In [32]: df['TimeStamp'].str.replace(r'(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)(.*)', r'\2/\3/\1\4')
Out[32]: 
0    06/08/2016 17:19:53
1    06/08/2016 17:19:54
2    06/08/2016 17:19:54
Name: TimeStamp, dtype: object
```

This uses regex to rearrange pieces of the string *without first parsing the
string as a date*. This is faster than the first method (mainly because it skips
the parsing step), but it also has the disadvantage of not checking that the
date strings are valid dates.

Comment: Hello @unutbu this worked. yes I noticed the slowness when running that line also once it was done I converted it to datetime using pd.to_datetime and it was very slow compared with when df['TimeStamp'] was string. will this procedure be faster than applying the str function over a loop? specially for a dataframe for million of records, doing a loop, I think is not a good idea.

Comment: Right. Avoid the Python loop if you can. Using `DatetimeIndex.strftime` is *much* faster than using a Python loop, parsing each date-string as a date and calling `strftime`.

Comment: @unutbu You don't need the `DatetimeIndex`, `strftime` is also available from the `.dt` accessor.

Comment: @joris: Ah, great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For most common date and datetime formats, pandas `.to_datetime` function can parse them without we providing format. 
For example:

`df.TimeStamp.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))`

And in the example given from the question,

`df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')`

will give us the same result.

Using `.apply` will be efficient if you have multiple columns.

Of course, providing the parsing format is necessary for many situations.  For a full list of formats, please see https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html.